# How do I find which facebook messenger apps are linked with a facebook page through the facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have been trying this out in the graph api explorer. Here are the steps I have been following:

1. Get a user access token with the permissions publish_actions, ads_management, manage_pages, publish_pages, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions, pages_show_list, and user_events.
2. I GET the `me/accounts` endpoint and get this object:

   ```
   {
     "data": [
       {
         "access_token": "thisIsWhereTheAccessTokenGoes",
         "category": "Shopping & Retail",
         "category_list": [
           {
              "id": "200600219953504",
              "name": "Shopping & Retail"
           }
         ],
         "name": "Some Page",
         "id": "123456789",
         "perms": [
           "ADMINISTER",
           "EDIT_PROFILE",
           "CREATE_CONTENT",
           "MODERATE_CONTENT",
           "CREATE_ADS",
           "BASIC_ADMIN"
         ]
       }
     ],
     "paging": {
       "cursors": {
         "before": "MTk1NDA4MDM2NDYyMDY5MAZDZD",
         "after": "MTk1NDA4MDM2NDYyMDY5MAZDZD"
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. I copy the access token and page id from the above page object and paste it into the graph api explorer in the appropriate places.
4. I GET the endpoint `{page-id}/subscribed_apps`
5. I get this empty array:

   ```
   {
     "data": [
     ]
   }
   ```
6. However if I go to my facebook app dashboard and go to the messenger settings and generate a page access token for the same page that I was getting in the graph api explorer, and then I paste that token into the explorer and get the `{page-id}/subscribed_apps` endpoint I actually get the app info that I was looking for. Something like this:

   ```
   {
     "data": [
       {
         "link": "https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=555555555555",
         "name": "Test Messenger Bot",
         "id": "555555555555"
       }
     ]
   }
   ```

I thought this could be because my app was in testing mode, but I tried to create a bot on chatfuel and linked it to the same facebook page and could not see that app listed under `subscribed_apps` either. I am thinking there is maybe some kind of permissions issue? I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Presumably you did not switch to your own app id in GAE before generating the access token, so that you created a token for the GAE app, and not your own ...? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/#Reading: _"Note that we will only return information about the current app"_

Comment: Thank you, CBroe. I get what you are saying. That sounds like the problem. My goal is to get a list of all Facebook Messenger Bot App IDs that are being used by a Facebook Page. I thought I could get the IDs of all apps with webhooks listening to events from a Facebook Page with the method above, but apparently not? Do you know of any other ways I could get the app IDs of all Messenger Apps that are associated with a Facebook Page?

Comment: My guess is that limitation is in place simply to protect this kind of "sensitive" business information ... Just because I drive two cars, does not mean that manufacturer A had any right to know I drive one made by B also, and vice versa. That you as the page admin can see all those apps via the UI, is a different story - that information stays with you, whereas 3rd-party apps, that are used on a multitude of pages, could easily collect such information en masse, and use it for their own interests.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for you help!